# Will Ubuntu replace dpkg with snappy?

Tags: dpkg

My apologies for being uninformed, but I couldn't find the answer through Google or read/understand a definite answer out of [Mark's announcement](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1479).

Are there plans to replace dpkg in its entirety with the new snappy approach? Or will this feature be reserved for the mobile/core (and maybe desktop) branch?

Comment: The answer is YES, dpkg will be still used.

Comment: Thank you, @Pilot6! Will there be a more definite announcement or clarification at some point, or was it just a misunderstanding on my part?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I am an Ubuntu Core Developer, Ubuntu Server developer and a developer on the Canonical Server Team.

Yes, Xenial Xerus, scheduled for 16.04 LTS, will use dpkg as normal. While we continue to develop Snappy, including for Ubuntu Server users, Snappy will not replace the regular apt and dpkg based server release in Xenial.

Comment: Thank you for writing something actually comprehensible, instead of the stream-of-consciousness buzzwords permeating Mark's article.

Comment: Thank you for an authoritative answer.  If you know, could you perhaps say what it is that Snappy solves that could not be done with the existing Debian tools?

Comment: (And maybe what downsides it has?)

Comment: @RobieBasak, thanks for answering. Once Snappy has been fully developed, will it replace `dpkg` and `apt`? If so, will it still handle '.deb' packages (to install the many applications still not available in repositories)?